# magento site redirecting to http://www.hpslightshop.com/

Tags: apache, magento

Today I'm trying to configure the sub-domain in Apache web-server(Centos) using virtual-host.Sub domain pointing is working fine.

**error**

magneto site redirecting to different site (http://www.xxxx.com/)

**Note :-**

1.IN core_config_data table.I have changed the data to http://test.xxxx.com/

2.cleared /var/cache and /var/session folders in your magento root

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/    
ServerName test.xxxx.com    
ErrorLog /var/log/xxxx_error_log                      
CustomLog /var/log/xxx_access_log               
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

if you run

`select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%`' is changed or not

Comment: Thank you. i have found that there was a multiple stores in the database and each stores pointing to individual site URL.